# NSUrl returns nil while unwrapping

Tags: ios, swift, exception, nsurl, null

NSUrl returns nil while running this code.

```
let urlString = "https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?text=baby asian elephant&method=flickr.photos.search&format=json&nojsoncallback=1&extras=url_m&safe_search=2&api_key=ed8f0359ce87560e56cda1fe71e8ad9d"
let url = NSURL(string: urlString)!
```

Throws an:

```
EXC_BAD_INSTRUCtION
```

Any ideas why this is happening.

Thank you.

Comment: i would guess the whitespaces are the problem since whitespaces in urls are not allowed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem are the whitespace in the `urlString`.

They need to be replaced. Whitespaces in URLs are written as `%20` instead of :

```
let urlString = "https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/text=baby%20asian%20elephant&method=flickr.photos.search&format=json&nojsoncallback=1&extras=url_m&safe_search=2&api_key=ed8f0359ce87560e56cda1fe71e8ad9d"
```

I am guessing that you somehow insert the `text` parameter by yourself?! This parameter would need to be escaped first, Zaph has already pointed out the neccessary methods for that case.

Answer (score 2):

There shouldn't be whitespace in the URL.

Answer (score 1):

You can't have white spaces in the urlString

```
let urlString = "https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?text=baby%20asian%20elephant&method=flickr.photos.search&format=json&nojsoncallback=1&extras=url_m&safe_search=2&api_key=ed8f0359ce87560e56cda1fe71e8ad9d"
let url = NSURL(string: urlString)!
```

Answer (score 1):

The URL String has characters that need to be escaped: the space characters. Here is example code to escaped the URL:

```
let urlString = "https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?text=baby asian elephant&method=flickr.photos.search&format=json&nojsoncallback=1&extras=url_m&safe_search=2&api_key=ed8f0359ce87560e56cda1fe71e8ad9d"

let escapedString = urlString.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(.URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet())

if  let escapedString = escapedString {
    let url = NSURL(string: escapedString)
    if let url = url {
        println("url: \(url)")
    }
}
```

Output

```
url: https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?text=baby%20asian%20elephant&method=flickr.photos.search&format=json&nojsoncallback=1&extras=url_m&safe_search=2&api_key=ed8f0359ce87560e56cda1fe71e8ad9d
```